# Can Shimano Claris R2000 shifters be paired with Claris 2400 derailleurs?

Tags: shifter, derailleur-rear

Can I use the modern looking shifters with the older model derailleurs without any problems in shifting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is that all Shimano road components of the same 'speed' (8, 9, 10 etc) are compatible. There are exceptions though, most people seem to not realize that Shimano publishes very detailed [specifications and compatibility information](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/) which is worth checking.

Check [Rear Drivetrain Compatibility](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-453&acid=C-454), search on page for 'RD-24400', you see there is a connection for both SS and GS types to the ST-R2000 shifter.

Check [Front Drivetrain Compatibility](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-453&acid=C-455), search on page for 'FD-2400', you see there is *not* a connection ST-R2000 shifter. The R2000 shifter is only compatible with the FD-R2000 front derailleur.

It's generally known that Shimano used the same 'classic' cable pull ratio for all road groups up to 10 speed which is responsible for wide compatibility, but that holds most true for *rear* derailleurs. I suspect that Shimano changed the front cable pull ratio on the R2000 groupset for better front shifting.

You could try the older front derailleur with the newer shifter and it may work OK. If it doesn't swap out the front derailleur, they are relatively inexpensive compared to the shifters.

Comment: The Dura-Ace parts having 8 speeds or less use a different cable pull ratio. So certainly not all road groups up to 10 speed use the same cable pull ratio.

Comment: OK, it could have been an update to https://www.reddit.com/r/bikewrench/comments/74xyig/are_shimano_front_derailleur_shifters_and/ "new cable pull ratio, that to the extent of my current knowledge, has only propagated from Dura-Ace down to Tiagra (4700)." However, it should also be present at Sora then, r2000 and r3000 have even a single shared manual.

Comment: @VladimirF I don’t thing R2000 has the 11 speed cable pull seen on 4700. It’s only the FD that Shimano says is incompatible. That may be for other reasons than cable pull or they just don’t feel it works quite as well as it should.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I do understand this is only about the FD, the RD is standard pull 100%. I actually believe the RD is too but I do admit I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use any 8 or 9 speed rear derailleur (with the traditional cable pull ratio, but SRAM 1:1 does not matter here) with 8 speed shifters. The same for the front ones. That includes these two Claris generations.

Your combination is compatible.